# Forms gets submitted twice when I try to prevent form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page, there is a form with `id=save-questions-form`. I'm trying intercept form submit  by the following way:

```
$('#save-questions-form').on('submit', handler);
```

There is a content of the handler function below (inside ajax, a post-request is sent to the form action):

```
function handler() {
    $.ajax({...});
    return false;
}
```

In this case, the form is sent twice.
This option below doesn't help either.

```
function handler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({...});
    return false;
}
```

But if I'm trying to do the same things without `ajax`, for example like this:

```
function handler(event) {
    return false;
}
```

then it works fine, and form isn't sent.

I solved this problem in the following way:

```
$('document').on('submit', '#save-questions-form', saveQuestionsSubmit);
```

In this case, everything works fine and form doesn't send twice.
But I don't understand how it works? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding the `submit` event handler multiple times?

Comment: Can we see your HTML code ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Absolutely not. this case is excluded

Comment: Try `$('#save-questions-form).submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $.ajax(); return false; })`

Comment: @MariosNikolaou logically that's identical to the first example in the question

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I tried this, and I wrote out this in my question!

Comment: @RomanAndreev at what point do you add the event handler to the form? Also, if you add `$('#save-questions-form').off('submit')` before adding the handler does it fix the problem? One other thing to try, click 'preserve log' in the console so that errors don't disappear when the page is unloaded. I suspect an error is occurring in your event handler logic which is preventing the `return false` from being executed.

Comment: `return false` doesn't submit the form.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I add the event handler to the form when a document is ready `$(function() {//my function here});`. Preserve log doesn't show any errors. And yes, if I add `off` before adding the handler it fixes the problem. But why it happens? I don't add another handler for the `submit` event to the same form anywhere else. How can I found out it?

Comment: Add `event.stopPropagation()` at the top, right after `e.preventDefault()`.  As you've noted, without any code, just a `return false` you don't get the problem.  This indicates that the `return false` is not getting reached.  Return false is the same as the above 2 lines, but occurs at the end (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/2181514) so if the function exists before this it won't be hit.

Comment: `And yes, if I add off before adding the handler it fixes the problem.` Then this definitely means that the handler is being bound multiple times. If your logic doesn't do it, then it must be happening somewhere else. Without seeing the complete sample of your code we can't really help you any further.

Comment: I think you are probably getting an error somewhere, so return false is not getting reached, try just returning false, no other stuff, see if that works and work up from there

Comment: When you say the form is being sent twice, do you mean you are receiving the form data twice, or are you seeing two AJAX requests to your endpoint? If it's the latter, it might be that you are seeing a preflight  (OPTIONS) check...